# How do you use JMeter with Digest Authentication?

Tags: authentication, jmeter, digest-authentication

I'm trying to use JMeter to test a web application, but there is no documentation on how to set it up to use digest authentication.  I've tried using the proxy server to record the authentication, but the requests have no information that I can see in the UI and playback doesn't work.  It seems the default with JMeter is basic authentication, though I've heard hints that digest can be used.  A simple example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter supports DIGEST authentication using Authorization Manager and httpclient
Using HTTP 3.1 :

in jmeter.Properties , uncomment:

httpclient.parameters.file=full path to bin folder/httpclient.parameters

in httpclient.parameters, uncomment:

http.authentication.preemptive$Boolean=true

Using HTTP Client 4:

hc.parameters.file=full path to bin folder/hc.parameters

in hc.parameters, uncomment:

http.authentication.preemptive$Boolean=true

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [the online manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Login_Config_Element)?

Answer (score 0):

I used JMeter (version 3.0) with Digest Authentication to consume RESTful APIs(, which were protected by [Spring Digest Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/basic.html))

I configured JMeter as below. And it worked perfectly for me. FYI:

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Check also [the JMeter doc on HTTP Authentication Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager))